# Outlook (Standalone application) add-in for Mac OS

Tags: java, macos, javafx, outlook, outlook-addin

We have created outlook[standalone application] add-in for Windows using joa addin based on the following link https://github.com/wolfgangimig/joa. We need the same to be done for Mac OS also.
     As joa is based on COM technology, we are unable to use it for Mac. Kindly suggest me the steps to create outlook add-in for Mac OS. Share some links if any code is available for creating outlook add-in for Mac.

Comment: This is not a Java question.

Comment: The joa addin that I have used for windows outlook addin is of java and javafx

Answer (score 1):

I too created outlook custom addin for windows using joa.As joa uses windows registry for saving data it works only on windows.Refer this link https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/outlook/add-ins/quick-start?tabs=visual-studio-code for Mac os.

Comment: I too saw the above link...Thank u:)

Answer (score 0):

Mac version of Outlook does not support COM based addins - they are Windows specific. It only supports JS addins (also supported by the Windows, iOS, and Android versions of Outlook) - see https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/outlook/add-ins/